# How to configure a Controller in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to add a `redirect` after `sign_in` in the `new_user_session` path.

My helper methods:

```
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    debugger
    redirect_to(session[:return_to]||default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to]=request.fullpath if request.get?
  end
```

This is for an e-bank website that receives data from other websites and redirects to the new_user_session path asking for the user to sign in. I set-up Devise with default User model. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into devise wiki?

Comment: Which gives you after_sign_in_path_for method, so you can specify root after sign in where you want to redirect a user and you can add your custom logic into a method and then you can send back to your route.

Comment: I want to redirect just after the specific situation like processing the other websites data, not every time after sign_in. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the devise session controller like this

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController


    #In this method check your logic
      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        #check your specific situation here and do whatever you want 
        if condition meet
           ##your logic goes here
        else
          root_path // or redirect after logged in
        end
      end
    end
```